# Array.push() in a nested for loop causing last value of parent loop to be pushed

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an object that has two keys with array values:

```
{
  list: ["a", "b", "c"],
  commands: [
    {
      type: "LOAD_URL",
      url: "https://example.com",
    },
  ],
}
```

I need to loop through the Object.list array, and add it's value to each of the Object.commands object. I wrote the following function to achieve this:

```
const addListValueToCommands = (valuesObj) => {
  let modifiedCommands = [];

  for (let a = 0; a < valuesObj.list.length; a++) {
    let currentListValue = valuesObj.list[a];

    for (let b = 0; b < valuesObj.commands.length; b++) {
      let newCommand = valuesObj.commands[b];
      newCommand.currentVal = currentListValue;
      console.log(newCommand)                // NOTE: logs correctly
      modifiedCommands.push(newCommand);         // NOTE: pushes incorrectly
    }
  }

  console.log(modifiedCommands);             // NOTE: logs wrong data
};
```

The goal is for it to return this:

```
[
 { type: 'LOAD_URL', url: 'https://example.com', currentVal: 'a' },
 { type: 'LOAD_URL', url: 'https://example.com', currentVal: 'b' },
 { type: 'LOAD_URL', url: 'https://example.com', currentVal: 'c' }
]
```

However it returns:

```
[
  { type: 'LOAD_URL', url: 'https://example.com', currentVal: 'c' },
  { type: 'LOAD_URL', url: 'https://example.com', currentVal: 'c' },
  { type: 'LOAD_URL', url: 'https://example.com', currentVal: 'c' }
]
```

I've never run into something like this before. I've tried messing with different variable scopes, cloning the arrays and command objects, but I can't seem to get anything to work.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a copy of the object without mutating the original data with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

This approach breaks the same object reference of the object.

```
let newCommand = { ...valuesObj.commands[b] };
```

```js
const addListValueToCommands = (valuesObj) => {
  let modifiedCommands = [];

  for (let a = 0; a < valuesObj.list.length; a++) {
    let currentListValue = valuesObj.list[a];
    for (let b = 0; b < valuesObj.commands.length; b++) {
      let newCommand = { ...valuesObj.commands[b] };
      newCommand.currentVal = currentListValue;
      modifiedCommands.push(newCommand);
    }
  }

  console.log(modifiedCommands);
};

const object = { list: ["a", "b", "c"], commands: [{ type: "LOAD_URL", url: "https://example.com" }] };

addListValueToCommands(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You ma'am, deserve a raise.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
let newCommand = valuesObj.commands[b]
```

so `newCommand` has a reference to an entry in your commands array - as your variable `b` changes as the loop runs, this reference changes under your feet.

You can reduce your loop complexity and fix the bug by using `Array.map` and using the spread operator to copy your commands:

```js
const data = {
  list: ["a", "b", "c"],
  commands: [
    {
      type: "LOAD_URL",
      url: "https://example.com",
    },
  ],
}


const translateData = ({list,commands}) =>list.map(d=>({currentVal:d, ...commands[0]}))

console.log(translateData(data))
```